# Crawler Friendly CSS Ribbons

Tags: css

I have a [working 'css ribbon tag'](http://jsfiddle.net/k87CE/)

However, the HTML is very ugly:

```
          <div class="tag-holder">
              <div style="position:relative">
                <div class="triangle">    
                    <span>classic</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="position:relative">
                <div class="triangle">    
                    <span>open-assets</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style="position:relative">
                <div class="triangle">    
                    <span>open-music</span>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

in that I have to define the 'tags' wrapped by two divs that is then wrapped by a `tag-holder` div. This is very problematic for crawlers/screen readers as they are hard to read.

What css could I use so that I will have minimal HTML markup but still produce the same look? I'm thinking something that uses `:before` or some such psuedoselector would work but I'm not sure how to properly implement it.

I'm looking for a non-js solution, and preferably, works well on most browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by "Hard to read"

Comment: @Mr.Alien They're hard to read for screen readers (blind), they're not accessible. Especially problematic because this are meant to be blog post tags.

Comment: try like this in http://jsfiddle.net/k87CE/4/

Comment: @Kiran Nice implementation but still the same markup. I guess the heading makes it easier to parse for readers though.

Comment: so will it helps you or not?

Comment: From a screen reader point of view, I'd be more concerned about the context of those tags. Will it be obvious what they apply to? Are they headings that go with particular content? If so, how are they associated with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/t5YMA/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tag_holder">
    <div class="ribbon">classic</div>
    <div class="ribbon">open-assets</div>
    <div class="ribbon">classic</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ribbon {
  position:relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #5ad2f0;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
  margin:5px 0;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:12px;
  padding-left: 20px;   
}
.ribbon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 16px solid #5ad2f0;
}
.ribbon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  left:1px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid #3aacc9;
  z-index:-1
}
```